# Java Scheduled Executor: Does it guarantee to not run in parallel if task hast not yet finished

Tags: java, executor

does anyone know if the following java Method in the java.util.concurrent Package `ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate()`

absolutely guarantees, that the Runnable scheduled will never run in parallel in case the runnable from the "last" run did not yet finish:

For example (Pseudocode)

```
1.00 o'clock: scheduleAtFixedRate(MyRunnable, "Run ever Hour")`
//1.30 o'clock: MyRunnable Has finished (everthing is fine)
2.00 o'clock: MyRunnable is triggered to run again
3.00 o'clock: MyRunnable has NOT yet finished ==> What will happen here? 
Will java Simply SKIP the starting of MyRunnable (as the old instance has not yet 
finished) and try again at 4 o'clock or will Java start a NEW MyRunnable that then will 
run in parallel to the "old" MyRunnable.
```

Thank you very much
Jan

Comment: I doubt that asking this question was any faster than simply reading the Javadoc of the method you mentioned ;)

Comment: hello sfussenegger,
the problem was I read the java doc and searched for this information in the javadoc, but somehow overlooked it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29):

> If any execution of this task takes
>   longer than its period, then
>   subsequent executions may start late,
>   but will not concurrently execute.

Comment: Hello Bruno,
thanks! Well I really read and searched  the java docs for this, but I dont know how I could oversee this. Thank you very much for your help! Jan